# How to get the libraries you need into the bin folder when using IoC/DI

Tags: visual-studio, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor to do some dependency injection, specifically I've abstracted the DAL layer to interfaces that are now being loaded by DI.

Once the project is developed & deployed all the .bin files will be in the same location, but for while I'm developing in Visual Studio, the only ways I can see of getting the dependency injected project's .bin file into the startup project's bin folder is to either have a post-build event that copies it in, or to put in a manual reference to the DAL project to pull the file in.

I'm not totally thrilled with either solution, so I was wondering if there was a 'standard' way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you set the build output path of the concrete DAL project to be the bin folder of the dependent project?

Answer (score 0):

Mike: Didn't think of that, that could work, have to remember to turn off copy-local for any libraries / projects that are common between them